# Is there an R function for combining data frames on unmatched columns?

Tags: r, date, dataframe, aggregate, transform

I'm trying to sort a data frame based on several variables.

In my data frame, I have ID number (id), Name of person's phone plan (plan), when they started with that plan (start_date), Count of times someone switched plans (count_switch), comments person made about plan during phone call to customer service (comment), and date of comment (comment_date).

To get this data frame, I joined two data frames. One had id, plan, start_date, and count_switch. So, if one person switched plans one time, they would have two rows (one for where they started and one for where they switched to). The other data frame had id, comment, and comment_date.

I joined the two data frames on "id".

This is what I expected to get, if, for example, someone switched plans one time and called in three time while with their first plan and twice while with their second plan:

```r
id plan start_date count_switch comment comment_date
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Hi         8/3/2018
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Hello      9/1/2018
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Bad        12/22/2018
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Bye        2/1/2019
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Cool       3/1/2019
```

Instead, this is what I get:

```r
id plan start_date count_switch comment comment_date
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Hi         8/3/2018
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Hello      9/1/2018
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Bad        12/22/2018
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Bye        2/1/2019
1   A   8/1/2018       1         Cool       3/1/2019
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Hi         8/3/2018
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Hello      9/1/2018
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Bad        12/22/2018
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Bye        2/1/2019
1   B   1/1/2019       2         Cool       3/1/2019
```

I'm not sure how to get it so that I know that when someone made a specific comment, they were with a specific plan, based on their start_date and comment_date. I'd like it set up this way so I can trace the types of comments made before and after changing plans.

This is my first time posting here - sorry if this is long winded!

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Instead of describing the two dataframes, could you provide code that generates example dataframes, and the code of what you tried so far? See here for more info on how to create a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes, thanks for the response! data frame 1: 
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1), "plan" = c("A","B"), "start_date" = c("8/1/2018", "1/1/2019"), "count_switch" = c(1,2))

df1$start_date <- as.Date(df1$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")

data frame 2:
df2 <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,1,1), "comment" = c("Hi", "Hello", "Bad", "Bye", "Cool"), "comment_date" = c("8/3/2018", "9/1/2018", "12/22/2018", "2/1/2019", "3/1/2019"))

df2$comment_date <- as.Date(df2$comment_date, "%m/%d/%Y")

What I tried to do:
df <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by="id")

Please let me know if any other details would help!

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest code, but I believe this will accomplish what you're setting out to do.

You're currently merging using just the common `id` column. However, `merge()` does not know whether the `comment` values belong to `plan` `'A'` or `'B'`, so it assumes the worst and duplicates it for each `plan` value. What you need to do is also specify under which plan the `comment` values were generated under.

`data.table::fread()` is used to read in the little data you've included in your question (you won't need this package). First, all dates in both `data.frame` objects are changed to `Date` objects. Then, in the first `data.frame`, I added an `end_date` column using `tibble::add_column()` for logical comparisons later. I assumed that the data is "real", in the sense that all `start_date` and `comment_date` values are in the past. Finally, I compared the `comment_date` values against the `start_date` and `end_date` values to determine under which `plan` each `comment` was made. The resulting `data.frame` objects could then be combined with `merge()`.

```
library(data.table)
library(tibble)
df1 <- fread(
  'id plan start_date count_switch
    1   A   8/1/2018       1
    1   B   1/1/2019       2')
df1$start_date <- as.Date(df1$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df1 <- add_column(
  df1,
  end_date = c(df1$start_date[2:nrow(df1)], Sys.Date()),
  .after = 'start_date'
)
df2 <- fread(
  'id comment comment_date
    1 Hi         8/3/2018
    1 Hello      9/1/2018
    1 Bad        12/22/2018
    1 Bye        2/1/2019
    1 Cool       3/1/2019')
df2$comment_date <- as.Date(df2$comment_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df2 <- add_column(
  df2,
  plan = df1$plan[
    sapply(
      df2$`comment_date`, 
      function(x) {
        which(df1$start_date < x & x < df1$end_date)
      }
    )
  ],
  .after = 'id'
)
merge(df1, df2)
```

Running this code gave me...

```
   id plan start_date   end_date count_switch comment comment_date
1:  1    A 2018-08-01 2019-01-01            1      Hi   2018-08-03
2:  1    A 2018-08-01 2019-01-01            1   Hello   2018-09-01
3:  1    A 2018-08-01 2019-01-01            1     Bad   2018-12-22
4:  1    B 2019-01-01 2019-09-18            2     Bye   2019-02-01
5:  1    B 2019-01-01 2019-09-18            2    Cool   2019-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using `dplyr` that I find to be a little more understandable.

Creating your example data:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1), "plan" = c("A","B"),
                  "start_date" = c("8/1/2018", "1/1/2019"),
                  "count_switch" = c(1,2)) 
df1$start_date <- as.Date(df1$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")

df2 <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                  "comment" = c("Hi", "Hello", "Bad", "Bye", "Cool"),
                  "comment_date" = c("8/3/2018", "9/1/2018", "12/22/2018", "2/1/2019", "3/1/2019")) 
df2$comment_date <- as.Date(df2$comment_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now we create a new `end_date` column in `df1`:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(end_date = lead(start_date, order_by = id)) %>% 
  ungroup()

df1
#>      id plan  start_date count_switch end_date   
#> 1     1 A     2018-08-01            1 2019-01-01
#> 2     1 B     2019-01-01            2 NA
```

Now we can merge the dataframes, as you did, but then filter so that the comment date is between the `start_date` and `end_date` (or the `end_date` is `NA`):

```r
df <- merge(x=df1, y=df2, by="id") %>% 
  filter(comment_date >= start_date,
         (comment_date < end_date) | is.na(end_date))

df
#>   id plan start_date count_switch   end_date comment comment_date
#> 1  1    A 2018-08-01            1 2019-01-01      Hi   2018-08-03
#> 2  1    A 2018-08-01            1 2019-01-01   Hello   2018-09-01
#> 3  1    A 2018-08-01            1 2019-01-01     Bad   2018-12-22
#> 4  1    B 2019-01-01            2       <NA>     Bye   2019-02-01
#> 5  1    B 2019-01-01            2       <NA>    Cool   2019-03-01
```